# Is there PushSharp similar application in java?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I need to implement Push notifications for iOS and Android. I saw that PushSharp has support for push notifications for those devices. But it is written on c# is there similar library on java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is Google Could Messaging - http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

It is free and provides a simple way of implementing them.